# Differential Integrator Opamp Problem and recomendations

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, analog, integrator

I want to build a simple integrator circuit with differential amplifier. I simulate it in LTspice bu I am not sure it will be able to work or not. Because R3-1Meg and it seems to high value. Maybe, there is noise in non-inverting terminal and it can be cause some problem. Do you have any advice about that circuit before trying in the board?

Green signal is input, Blue is output.
[image]

Comment: R3 looks like 500 k.  You also need a 220p capacitor across R3 if you want to preserve the common mode rejection above DC.  We can't say if your values will work without knowing what your requirements and specs are.

Comment: It looks like a high-gain differential amp, distant from being an integrator. The graph looks random. V1 needs to be grounded, probably with some voltage offset (common mode range), but should not float. you need to tell what is the use of your circuitry and the specification of the use (requirement), then pros can answer better.

Comment: What op amp are you using? And why can't you just remove R2 and R3 and tie V1 and vp  to gnd.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few red flag issues.

1. Input 10V/n slew rate or 10,000 V/us exceeds 99.9% of all Op Amps so the amplifier will not work.
2. You don't have any integrator specs
3. The non-inverting input gain must match with the same C across Vin+ to gnd if using [ms] pulses.
4. nanosecond pulse integrators need only a passive solution with stripline circuit layout for controlled Zo.